# Using R code in Python

Tags: python, r

I am new to Python. Is it possible to use a script written in R syntax, in the Python environment, even if R is not installed in that particular system?

If yes, can we use the different external packages in R, such as

> quantmod

etc.?

Basically I have prepared a script in R using a few packages available and now I need to implement that in Python. Trying to understand the easiest way to do that. And the system where I need to use this does not have R installed.
Last option is for me to write the code from scratch in Python syntax.

Comment: Any severe reason, why not to install R on the target systems? There is no R Interpreter written in Python and no way to compile R to machine code, so you will have to ship R with your program in some hidden form, if not open and visible.

Comment: @Bernhard - Admin issues in installing R in the target system. So I guess I need to write the code from scratch in Python :-(

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa/

Comment: Any possibility to trigger an R process on a remote machine (where you are allowed to have R installed) and then send the result over the network?

Comment: It would have been great if I could do that, but sadly no. The Target system is my Office system, so can't connect my personal system with that :-(

Comment: There is a portable Version of R meant for Installation on a USB stick at https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/ Any chances to get that running without admin issues? I have colleagues who use Firefox from a stick, as the admin doesn't allow Installation of a browser except for preinstalled IExplorer. Why should anyone allow the installation of Python but not R? I know, the "why" does not matter...